# Realtime/zero-latency video stream: what codec parameters to use?

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I am writing an Android App which encompasses sending and receiving a video stream from a desktop PC. For the app to work properly we need as little latency as possible, sacrificing video quality if necessary. We are using `gstreamer 1.45` on both ends, but with the current pipeline we have at least 0.5s delay on a Galaxy Note S2, and thats if both devices are on the same network (later this should work via VPN).

The **sender** pipeline

```
appsrc name=vs_src format=time do-timestamp=true
    caps="video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1000" 
    ! videoconvert 
    ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=1 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96
    ! queue ! udpsink name=vs_sink host=%s port=%d async=false
```

The **receiver** pipeline

```
udpsrc name=vr_src 
    caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264"
    ! rtpjitterbuffer 
    ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 
    ! videorate ! videoconvert
    ! glimagesink name=vr_sink async=false
```

Setting `threads=2` or higher emits a gstreamer warning that it was compiled without multithreading support. I know that some devices offer hardware decoders, but the only way to access them reliably seems to be via `encodebin`/`decodebin`. I already tried using a `decodebin` but for some reason it complains that it can't find the required plugins (e.g. `No decoder to handle media type 'video/x-h264'`).

I am no expert by any means when it comes to streaming and video encoding/decoding, and getting the App to a working point was already a nightmare :/ If H264 should be inappropriate we can switch to any other codec supported by gstreamer. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We do live video streaming from desktop PCs to Raspberry Pis, and we spent an enormous amount of time tweaking both the encoding and decoding portions of our system.  Unfortunately most libraries and tools have their out-of-the-box settings geared towards trans-coding or general video playback (not live).  We ended up writing our own GStreamer element to do the encoding (using vaapi) and our own Raspberry Pi program to do the decoding (using OMX).

I can offer a few thoughts for you, but nothing specific for the Android decoding scenario, unfortunately.

- If you're encoding on a powerful desktop, like i3-i7, make sure you add queues for any significant operation: colorspace conversion, scaling, encoding, etc.  So in your pipeline, make sure there is a "queue" between "videoconvert" and "x264enc" so they run on seperate threads.
- As Ralf mentioned, you probably want to use only P frames, not B frames, and your x264enc settings likely already do this.
- We usually favor dropping frames and showing garbage over using a large jitter buffer.  We also adjust the QP (quality of the encode) on the fly to be within our networks means.  So I'd suggest adding sync=false to your receiving program.  You want to render a frame as soon as you have it.  This potentially makes your video less smooth, but if you have a large jitter buffer you're always gonna be delayed.  Better to adjust the stream to the network and get rid of the buffer.  x264enc has "qp-min" and "qp-max" properties you can try.
- Try adjusting the "latency" and "drop-on-latency" properties of your rtpjitterbuffer, or try getting rid of it altogether.
- One very nasty thing we discovered is that in the Raspberry Pi decoder it  seemed to always have some sort of builtin latency, no matter how live-optimized our stream was.  It turns out in the h264 stream there is something called a VUI packet that can be used to tell the decoder what type of stream to expect, and when we supplied this packet the decoder reacted very differently.

```
bitstream_restriction_flag : 1
motion_vectors_over_pic_boundaries_flag : 1 
max_bytes_per_pic_denom : 0 
max_bits_per_mb_denom : 0 
log2_max_mv_length_horizontal : 10 
log2_max_mv_length_vertical : 10 
num_reorder_frames : 0 
max_dec_frame_buffering : 1   --- this makes a huge difference
```

For reference: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=41053

So in the above VUI settings I tell the decoder that we'll have a max of one P frame that it needs to buffer.  It's crazy how much this helped.  Of course we had to also make sure our encoder did only send the one P frame.  I'm not sure this is possible to do do with x264enc.

This stuff can get pretty scary.  Hopefully someone else has the Android video chops to give you a simpler answer!

EDIT: Regarding queues, I don't parameterize them at all, and in a live streaming situation if your queues fill up you need to scale back (resolution, quality, whatever) anyway.  In GStreamer the queue element causes GStreamer to launch a new thread to handle the following portion of the pipeline.  You just want to make sure your encode/scaling/colorspace conversion elements work in isolation.

> gst-launch-1.0 [GET RAW VIDEO DATA] queue [SCALE] queue
>   [COLORSPACE CONVERT] queue [ENCODE] queue [SEND WHEREVER]

The above will give you five threads.

If you get nothing here, my recommendation is to hit up an Android video API subforum or mailing list to see if anyone else has live video going and if so what tweaks they made to their stream and decoder.

--- Addendum 1-5-18

We've also noticed that some streams can fill up the kernel socket buffer and result in packet drops--particularly on large keyframes.  So if you have a larger stream I recommend checking the kernel buffer size using `sysctl`:

```
sysctl net.core.rmem_max;  sysctl net.core.rmem_default
net.core.rmem_max = 212992
net.core.rmem_default = 212992
```

Append `net.core.rmem_max = whatever` in /etc/sysctl.conf on your receiving device, and on `udpsrc` set `buffer-size` to this new max value.  You can tell if you're still seeing drops by running something like this:

```
watch -d 'cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Udp: '
```

...or something like this on your receiving pipeline:

> export GST_DEBUG=2,rtpjitterbuffer:5
>
> gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5100
>   buffer-size=825984 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 !
>   rtpjitterbuffer latency=200 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse
>   disable-passthrough=true ! queue ! avdec_h264 output-corrupt=true !
>   queue ! videoconvert ! ximagesink 2>&1 | grep -i "buffer discon

--- Addendum 1-11-19

If you have the means to navigate the patent situation, the openh264 library from Cisco works very nicely.  It's very much tuned for live streaming.

https://github.com/cisco/openh264

https://www.openh264.org/BINARY_LICENSE.txt

There is a GStreamer plugin for it under `gst-plugins-bad`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! If nothing else shows up I'll accept this one :) One question though: how did you parametrize the queues? Did you just use the default settings, or did you adjust the internal buffers? Did you allow dropping new or old frames?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on queues. Using your suggestions I was able to reduce latency significantly! As for the `max_dec_frame_buffering` setting you mentioned, my guess is that this is controlled by the `ref` property (number of reference frames), which defaults to 1. The libav decoder has no such setting.

Comment: Great to hear, I'd be curious to see what your final pipeline was on each end.

Comment: I'm still iterating over some details. I'll post them when I'm content and leave you a note :)

Comment: Thank you for still continuing to update your answer! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am no expert by any means when it comes to streaming and video encoding/decoding, and getting the App to a working point was already a nightmare :/ If H264 should be inappropriate we can switch to any other codec supported by gstreamer

This is most probably not a codec-related issue: delays introduced by a codec occur when using B-frames, which IIRC x264 does not use in zero latency mode.

Other delays in real-time streaming applications are your

- encoding delay (e.g. can your phone encode the data fast enough if not you can try to reduce resolution/quality/bitrate)
- network (which on the LAN should not be an issue)
- jitter/playout buffer

I would suggest looking at the playout buffer, perhaps `gstreamer` has a way to set the duration? Also, the implementation of the playout buffer plays a big role in how real-time you can go e.g. in older versions of `VLC` one was able to set the network caching parameter really low e.g. in the order of 100ms. However in current versions of VLC this causes the video to not playback as data "arrives" late. `ffmpeg` on the other hand is better suited to playback real-time data with low latency. I'm not sure how `gstreamer` compares.

You can try experimenting with ~100ms and then adjust according to how it performs. This is assuming of course that you can set this parameter in `gstreamer`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately this is a little too broad to be immediately useful to me :/